# Customizing Spring Data queries

Tags: java, spring, jpa, mapping

I have 'iddId'(primary key) column and 'idd_id'(unused column) in the table. When I trying to execute
'findAll' method via Spring Data JPA I get empty 'iddId' field in created object because the hibernate query looks like:

```
select 'idd0_.idd_id as col_0_0_'...
```

I tried to map fields manually with a @Column(name = "iddId") annotation but nothing was changed. Then I tryed to add an additional field to the entity 'idd_id' which is annotated with @Column(name="idd_id) and received the exception:

```
'org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [idd] contains physical column name [idd_id] referred to by multiple logical column names: [idd_id], [iddId]'.
```

Is it possible to make a query like that: 'select idd0_.iddId as col_0_0_'?

```
public class Idd {
            @Id
            @Column(name = "iddId")
            private String iddId;

            @Column(name = "idd_id")
            private String idd_id;
}
```

MySql: 5.7.28

Spring Data: 2.2.2

Comment: is your idd_id column also a primary key in the table?

Comment: Please change the title to "Customizing Spring Data JPA queries"

Answer (score -1):

Just add:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

to application.properties